Can light blueshift from gravity assists?
I'm aware that light can redshift when escaping from a gravity well, and that it can blueshift when entering a gravity well of the observer. But is it also possible for light to blueshift from 'gravity assists'? That is, is it possible for light to enter the gravity well of a massive object with wavelength $\lambda$ and leave it with wavelength $\lambda - \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon \gg 0$, assuming no other masses are involved?

Have you seen ISW effect ?
